# Android Studio cant find xml resource for background in drawable folder

Tags: android, android-drawable

This Error occurs

> Error:(17, 29) No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'background' with value '@drawable/shape_empty_big'

Here my XML shape file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<stroke android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="12dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="12dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="12dp"
    android:topRightRadius="12dp" />
</shape>
```

This is how I use background for my `button`

```
android:background="@drawable/shape_empty_big"
```

Here a pic of my drawable directory

[drawable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXcQ7.png)

thx for help, i appreciate

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding project..

Comment: make sure your xml named shape_empty_big

Comment: Thank you so much Guruprasad. Cleaning and rebuildung fixed my problem. Have a nice week Guruprasad and Joe

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is ok, you can try to clean and rebuild your project.

Below the code that i use to obtain a round button:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="false">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="@color/white" />

        <corners
            android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
            android:topRightRadius="10dp"/>

    </shape>
</item>
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="@color/gray"/>
        <corners
            android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
            android:topRightRadius="10dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I met the same problem, but I solved it just now.

Just copy the drawable from 'drawable' to 'drawable-v24'.

At first, I only put my xml drawable file into the 'drawable' folder by Android Studio, but it won't auto-link that for you. A bug probably.